# div ignores height from style sheet

Tags: css, html, height

This is driving me crazy. I can't seem to control the height of the `div.down_arrow` element below -

```
...
<div id="filters">
    ...
    <span>All</span>
    <div class="down_arrow">
        <img src="images/down_arrow.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
```

I've got the following css -

```
#filters {
    float: right;
    padding: 24px 10px 0 0;
}

#filters div {
    display: inline;
}

#filters div.down_arrow,
#filters div.down_arrow img {
    height: 12px;
    width: 23px;
}

#filters div.down_arrow:hover ing {
        opacity: 0;
}
```

The safari developer tools tell me that the height and width of my `div.down_arrow` are still having effect (ie there's no line through the attributes - nothing else is overriding them). But the little popup on the screen shows the dimensions of the `div.down_arrow` to be 27px x 16px. I can see that the element is larger than the `img` element it contains.

I don't understand what's going - it looks like the height seems to be taken from the preceding span element (and I've no idea what's effecting the width).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`

The issue is you can only manually control the width/height of block elements, not inline elements.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! (Don't know why Safari isn't showing my height attribute as invalid).

Answer (score 2):

inline elements are not affected by height